# Leverage browser caching for Facebook, Google+, or other 3rd party resource files

Tags: google, facebook, page-speed, optimization

I tested my website with Google PageSpeed Insights.

I did cache optimization in my *.htaccess*, but it didn't affect resource files that are from Facebook and Google+

```
Leverage browser caching

    http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js (20 minutes)

    https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js (30 minutes)

    https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/…e:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2 (60 minutes)
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

You have no control over them because they are hosted by another provider. And honestly speaking you should not worry about them, it's up to Google, Facebook, etc to handle the caching accordingly to their need.

You could potentially proxy the URLs or download the files locally, but I don't encourage you to follow that route. In fact, you may potentially end up with a configuration that do not reflect the changes when the upstream provider publish an update, or simply conflict with the caching already applied by Google, Facebook, etc.

Comment: and if you absolutely must have these scripts, make them load asynchronous, after main page load is completed.

Comment: Wonderful that it's up to Google and FB, but I want *my* site to be faster. I can't control *my* site regarding this.

Comment: You're using _their_ services, probably for free, so it's unfortunately up to _them._

Answer (score 2):

You should consider removing third party JavaScript from Facebook and Google from your pages.  The only third party JavaScript I typically have is for advertising.

All of the social networks have ways that you can use plain links (no JavaScript) to share your page.  See [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120539/facebook-share-link-no-javascript).   You wouldn't be able to see stats for likes and +1 in the page though.

Comment: But that doesn't help when getting to cases such as loading third party JQuery libraries. Simone Carletti's answer would apply here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a high level conspiracy by web market icons like Google and Facebook.

I was using these scripts on my website which caused it to work slowly. When I removed the scripts, it achieved my goal (i.e. page speed 100/100).  My site is now performing very well. It opens almost like it is AMP supported.

So page speed matters. I think you should stand on your own not by holding Google or Facebook's hand. Just remove the code.  Your subscribers needs site performance but performance starts with website loading. If you are loser from beginning, there is no way to come first in any search engine in the world. If users come first on your website, no search engine can put you behind cause you start making challenges for search engines.

So my suggestion is remove the scripts and make your own for better user experience.

Comment: Welcome to this site.   I've edited this answer quite heavily because it did not meet our quality standards.   You had included a link to your own site.   That can be fine if it is needed to answer the question, but in this case it was not needed.   Your grammar and formatting needed many improvements.   I also removed the profanity which is not appropriate here.